# Can I ask for the hadith reference/number if i know the part of matn or the matn gist heard in a speech?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes hear hadiths through speeches or reading articles but due to bad memory I can't recall it exactly enough to search for the source, maybe if it's a mashhur hadith someone can let me know.
So Am I allowed to ask questions like "XYZ is the matn , does anyone know the source?"

This also includes questions asking about other history texts like "Imam Malik or Ibn kathir commented xyz, does anyone know the source of this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's fine we have a lot of questions of this kind and two relevant tags: [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification) and [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) which might be used for this purpose.

Here some examples of former questions:
With tag [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification):

- [Did Umar (RA) say, "A man should be like a child with his wives ..."?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37767/did-umar-ra-say-a-man-should-be-like-a-child-with-his-wives/37771).
- [Source and authentication of "Jihad Will Be Performed Until The Coming of the Hour"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50676/source-and-authentication-of-jihad-will-be-performed-until-the-coming-of-the-ho).
- [Is there a source for "Whoever says I don't know has given a fatwa"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46775/is-there-a-source-for-whoever-says-i-dont-know-has-given-a-fatwa) (has been taged [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) too).

With tag [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request):

- [Reference of Qunoot Nazila of Umar (RA)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49617/reference-of-qunoot-nazila-of-umar-ra).
- [The Hadith regarding "Ya Sariyya al-jabal", is it authentic or daif or False](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30412/the-hadith-regarding-ya-sariyya-al-jabal-is-it-authentic-or-daif-or-false).
- [What is the evidence of praying nafal from Maghrib to Isha in the masjid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51596/what-is-the-evidence-of-praying-nafal-from-maghrib-to-isha-in-the-masjid).

Note that the more information you could provide the easier one may find the source or the content etc.